# Please help me with URL routing

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'am a complete beginner to this routing and mod-reqrite,etc. stuff.
I followed a tutorial regarding URL routing here: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls , but couldnt get it to work.

I just want to route ALL and any kind of URL's such as

```
http://wettone.com/weblog/2000/01/01/example
http://wettone.com/weblog/2000/01/01
http://wettone.com/weblog/2000/01
http://wettone.com/weblog/2000
```

to my index.php script in weblog folder in document root with directory paths available as:

```
http://wettone.com/weblog/index.php?y=2000&m=01&d=01&n=example
http://wettone.com/weblog/index.php?y=2000&m=01&d=01
http://wettone.com/weblog/index.php?y=2000&m=01
http://wettone.com/weblog/index.php?y=2000
```

How can i do this. 
BTW, I prefer to keep it simple and not use any framework

Thanx in advance...

**EDIT: May I know why negative vote? What have I done wrong? Cannot I ask this type of question here?**

Comment: Nobody can guess why you're getting an internal server error. The webservers log will tell. Also this is super simple, please read a few more tutorials; consider writing a less meaningless title to find some.

Comment: Check out [ToroPHP](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP). Super tiny "framework" I stumbled upon this week. Basically only gives you what you're after and not much more: Routing/clean urls :)

Comment: ToroPHP is just what I wanted. Thank u sooo much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /weblog/


RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3&n=$4
```

Comment: it dint worked. giving internal server error. my index.php is in weblog folder and i have put htaccess in document root. is it correct ?

Comment: @NitinBansal : edited the code please check it now

Comment: `.htaccess` should be in same directory as the index.php, no? And the `RewriteBase` should be set to the "webroot" I believe. (`/` if hosted at `example.com`, `/foo/` if hosted at `example.com/foo`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

so basically You want everything to map to index.php?
If yes, here's snippet taken from symfony1 htaccess

```
# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

in php You must then use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], if I remember correctly, to parse uri and decide what to show

Best is to just use symfony2 component for this job http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html :)

Comment: Thnx...i tried but it gave me "Internal Server Error" error. Whats wrong? BTW, I have placed this htaccess in my document root and index.php is in weblog folder. is it correct?

Comment: do You have mod_rewrite turned on, and after do You restarted apache?

Comment: ok, mod_rewrite was commented, but i uncomented it and restarted apache. LEt me tery few more permuatations/combinations